# Django pass request.POST and request.FILES in a editprofile form

Tags: django, django-forms, request

I have a view that enables users to edit their profiles (usual name, username etc) and a image contained in an `ÌmageField` within the `UserProfile`:

```
@login_required
def editprofile(request):
        user = request.user
        if request.method == 'POST':
                edit_form = EditProfileForm(data = request.POST, user = user)
                if edit_form.is_valid():
                        user = edit_form.save()
                        request.user.message_set.create(message='Votre profil a été modifié.')
                        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
                dict = {'first_name':user.first_name, 'last_name':user.last_name, 'email':user.email, 'username':user.username}
                edit_form = EditProfileForm(user = user, data = dict)
        tpl_dict = {'form' : edit_form}
        return render_to_response('editprofile.html', tpl_dict, RequestContext(request))
```

and the form is:

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 100, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 100, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    username = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    avatar = forms.ImageField(required = False)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user

    def save(self):
        user = self.user
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        profile = user.get_profile()
        profile.avatar = self.cleaned_data['avatar']
        profile.save()
        return user
```

the problem is that i need to pass a `request.FILES' to the form!
I've tried

```
edit_form = EditProfileForm(data = request.POST, request.FILES, user = user)
```

and other variants without succes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are overriding the constructor of a form it is a good idea to pass the arguments named instead of just in order. So, I would do:

```
edit_form = EditProfileForm(user=user, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
```

That way it is clear to someone reading the code that you have a non-standard form that expects a user argument and it makes explicit which arguments you are passing.

Alternatively, if you'd insist on calling the constructor without naming the arguments, the correct way to do so is:

```
edit_form = EditProfileForm(user, request.POST, request.FILES)
```

since `user` is the first argument to your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
edit_form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user = user)
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to override a form's __init__ is to listen for extra kwargs:

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.Form):
    # [fields]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', default_user) # fetch `user` and remove from kwargs
        super(EditProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user
```

This leaves the form's original signature essentially untouched, and you can instantiate it as normal, with your extra argument tacked on the end:

```
EditProfileForm(request.POST, user=user)
EditProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=user)
```

etc.